# How do I stop my future builder from updating the screen?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a problem and it happens when I use the camera and it is that my screen is updated. I guess it is because of the future builder and the set state that I use.
Example:: I edit the 2 textforms and when I want to use the camera and take the photo, the 2 textforms are updated as they were before editing it without using any update method.

If the text "Roxana Luz" and "RoxanaLuz19@gmail.com" appears, I change to "Roxana L" and "Roxana@gmail.com" and then I open the camera and take the photo.

"Roxana Luz" and "RoxanaLuz19@gmail.com" reappear as it was from the beginning.

I will leave code and image::

---

```
Widget FotoF2(String fotousuarioo){
    return new Container(
      child:image==null? newphoto(fotousuarioo):photoprofile(),
    );
  }

****************************
 Future <dynamic> futureup;

  @override
  void initState() {
    print("initstate");
   futureup =  editarperfilservices.EditarPerfil() ;
    super.initState();
  }


Future OpenCamara() async {

    final pickedFile = await  ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera); 
    setState(() {
      if (pickedFile != null) {
        image =File(pickedFile.path);

      } });
  }
****************************************
  Widget FullName(NombreUsuario){
    return new Container(
        child:  new TextFormField(
          controller: NombreUsuario,
            suffixIcon: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.cancel,color: Colors.black,),
                  onPressed: () {
                    NombreUsuario.clear();
                  }
              )
    );
  }

*****************************************
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

body: Container(
          child: FutureBuilder(
              future: futureup,
    builder:(context, AsyncSnapshot  snapshot) {
      List  busqueda = snapshot.data;
      if(snapshot.hasData ) {
      return   Center(
          child: new Container(
          child: new ListView.builder(
    itemCount: busqueda.length,
    itemBuilder: (context,i){
      Correo.text = busqueda[i].UsuarioCorreo ;
      NombreUsuario.text = busqueda[i].UsuarioApodo ;
      fotousuarioo = busqueda[i].FotoUsuario;
      return Container(
        child: ListView(
          shrinkWrap: true,
            children:[
              SizedBox(height: 18,),
              FotoF2(fotousuarioo),
              SizedBox(height: 18,),
              FullName(NombreUsuario),
              SizedBox(height: 18,),
              CorreoF2(Correo),

            ]
        ),
      );
    }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: It's a little unclear still to me what your issue is with what you're expecting to happen vs actually happening. But by calling setstate when you open your camera, it will rebuild everything within that build.

Comment: What I want is that if I change some text in the text form field and then open the camera, it doesn't go back to the original text. which came from the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Break out your FotoF2 into its own Stateful Widget.  You call setState in the parent it appears, which forces an entirely new build of your page and creates a brand new snapshot.  If you break it out, it'll only rebuild the image, as you want.

Comment: put that method FotoF2  outside the future builder?? the image and the text are fromdatabase

Comment: No. An entirely new StatefulWidget.  On the intial build, you'll get that StatefulWidget with the fotousuarioo (so name that as a required field in the new widget).   But then when tapped (or I guess you have imagePicker  open automatically if the image is null), it will process ImagePicker and setState only on your image, not the entire parent widget tree.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't understand you completely, could you help me with a code example?

Comment: You'll need to understand the fundamentals of Stateful and Stateless widgets.  London App Brewery's course on flutter is very inexpensive and I highly recommend it.  It's a great place to start for getting a grasp on OOP and Flutter.

Comment: I solved the problem, thanks for the advice and now I understand better the stateful widget when you use it with a future builder, what you told me helped me a lot. 
I created another stateful widget for the image and photo and that set state updated only the stateful widget of the photo